# MySql creating a unique key on two columns

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, mariadb

I'm trying to create a Many-to-Many relationship, but having a hard go on making the intermediary table unique on two columns.  Here is my schema for the three tables.

```
create table users 
( 
id int primary key auto_increment,
username varchar(255) not null,
password varchar(255) not null,
email varchar(255) not null

)

create table products
(
 id int primary key auto_increment,
 product_name varchar(255) not null,
 product_description text(999) not null,
 product_price int not null
)

create table users_products
(
  id int primary key auto_increment,
  user_id int null,
  product_id int null
  unique key 'users_product_index' ('user_id', 'product_id')
)
```

Where I use this SQL code, it gives me this error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''user_id', 'product_id')
)' at line 6
```

It is obviously just practice but the whole items is allow allow more than one user list out products to sell.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you try using backticks `\`` insead of single quotes `'` when specifying columns in `unique key 'users_product_index' ('user_id', 'product_id')`?

Comment: Maybe it is missing a comma after `product_id int null` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing a comma.  But there are several less-than-optimal issues with the schema.  See tips:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

Comment: The example you showed actually worked.  Thanks for the help and the website.  It looks like a resource I really needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
create table users_products
(
  id int primary key auto_increment,
  user_id int null,
  product_id int null,
  unique key `users_product_index` (`user_id`, `product_id`)
)
```

Note the comma after `product_id int null` and the ` instead of '.

I hope it helps.